# Adding more hard negatives while training a classifier leads to more false positives

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision

Due to my limited knowledge of programming in machine learning (using Matlab) i am not able to find a way to this problem ... I think my question will test the patience of most of the readers!

I am trying to recognize traffic signs using well know Belgium data set in Matlab. This data set contains around 4000 positive windows and 3000+ negative images from where we can crop negative windows for training a classifier. I am using adaboost classifier, weak learners in each stage are [32 128 512 2048] (from a paper). The steps which i am following are,

1- Train a classifier using all positives & 20,000 randomly cropped negatives windows in first stage,

2- Use the trained classifier from previous stage on negative images for mining hard negatives. When 20,000 hard negatives are sampled, train the classifier in previous+1 stage and move to next stage,

3- goto step 2

The problem which i encountered is spurious false positives while testing. But when i decreased the amount of addition of hard negatives in each stage by 1/4 i.e. 5000, the system seems to be much more stable than before giving too less false positives. As far as it is in my confined knowledge that, adding more hard negatives will make the system robust against false positives. But it is working the other way.

How can i determine particular amount of hard negatives to be added in each stage for a stable system? Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this!

Answer (score 0):

When there are 20000 negatives and 4000 positives, are you adjusting the weights accordingly? In my opinion, the weights should sum to one while maintaining the proportion. The weight of each +ve examples should be `0.5/4000` and accordingly determine the -ve weights too. If you are not adjusting the weights, then it explains why you are getting better performance for 5000 since the weight imbalance becomes less severe.

Comment: by weights you mean the proportion of negative and positive samples? can you elaborate your answer more ... i am a slow learner

Comment: In traditional adaboost, every example has a weight assigned to it. Which adaboost and what weak learner are you using?

Comment: weak classifiers are decision trees. i am using the adaboost provided in piotr dollar toolbox http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/index.html

Comment: okay i think i got it. there is a child function available to the adaboost funtion. i think i have to alter the weights of positive and negative here! http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/index.html